# how to make javascript load single time and live across all web pages

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web

I am creating one mqtt web application, in that when message is published from server i get one json array in mqtt javascript function.

I have one subscribe page from that user can subscribe(subscribe code is in mqtt javascript) ,so once the user login, there is multiple pages , user can check data for each page.

But the issue i am facing is, when page is redirect it will again ask to subscribe for the user.

**Currently i am loading that script on master page so it loads every time on every page and timer code does not execute**

Comment: You need to implement single page application if you want to achieve this. The `js ` will be re executed every time you load a page, by fetching a new html file from server. If you want your javascript to live across pages you need to change content of the page instead of loading a new page.

Comment: If it's included in the master page then it will also be included in every page that uses the master page.  You need to post some code if you want help - it may just be a simple error in your Javascript, but without seeing it we can't help you.

Comment: I want  javascript to live across all pages.how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you load a new full page the scripts are re-loaded and start again from new.

If you want client scripts/state to live across pages then you need a single page app (e.g. Angular/Ember etc or custom scripts). An SPA basically uses javascript to manually load fragments of pages from the server and integrate them into the current document while maintaining the current script context. This way client script variables/parameters can be maintained.

Alternatively, you can use cookies or server-side session to persist state across full page loads.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to save data and recover it in other pages you can use one of the solutions such as session storage or webSQL or window.name ...

```
window.name = JSON.tostring(myData);
```

> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

but if you want to have only one page load you can look at other frameworks, like Vuejs

> https://forum.vuejs.org/t/independent-vue-2-components-one-instance-or-several/4228
>
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html